# Code works from project but not from a Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

**Update:** Refactored the code at the end below to this:

```
  let getMembersIDs = eventID => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('events').doc(eventID).get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data().members)
          return doc.data().members
        } 
        else throw new Error ('Event does not exist!', doc.id)
      })
  }
  let dispatchToMembers = (arrayMembersIDs, data) => {
    return Promise.all(
      arrayMembersIDs.map(memberID => {
        if (data.at===memberID) data.type = 'pm'
        else data.content = 'New message in an event chat you participate to.'
        console.log('Sending now to: ', memberID)
        return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(memberID).collection('inbox').add({
          content: 'You were mentioned in a recent chat: ' + data.content,
          type: data.type
        })
      })
    )
  }
  getMembersIDs(data.target).then(members => dispatchToMembers(members, data)).then(() => {
    console.log('Message dispatched!')
    res.end()
    return true
  })
  .catch(err => { 
    console.error(err);
    response.status(500).send(err);
    return true;
  })
})
```

*It does work* when I run it from my project, replacing *admin.firestore()* with *db.* However when embedded within a cloud function it does not work: the cloud function returns codes 204 and 200 but the desired db operation does not seem to occur. Pulling my hair as I don't understand why.

**Outdate**: I am not able to debug the following piece of code. A simple cloud function with two parts (a read, a write) chained with promises.

```
exports.discuss = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('events').doc(data.target).get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) return doc.data().members
    else throw new Error ('Doc does not exist ', doc.id)
  })
  .then(members => {
    let promises = []
    members.forEach(u => {
      ...
      let promise = new Promise(res => {
        admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(u).collection('inbox').add({...})
        res(u)
      })
      promises.push(promise)
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then(() => {
    response.send('ok')
    return;
 })
 .catch(err, response.status(500).send(err))
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You generate that 500 code with this line:

```
.catch(err, response.status(500).send(err))
```

The client that invokes the Cloud Function should be getting the error message in the response body. But you'll also want to log it on the server with:

```
.catch(function(err) { 
  console.error(err);
  response.status(500).send(err);
  return true;
})
```

Comment: Did that and it made 0 difference to the cloud function error log. I am starting to wonder whether my Promise.all statement forces a sychroneous resolution of the query when perhaps Firestore would like to resolve them one by one. Still, this lack of logging is troubling.

Comment: updated the original question above. I would be very grateful if you had a lead for me on this...